# Low MSE loss for object detection but really bad results

Tags: neural-network, convolution

I am training object detection using CNN

I am using MSE as loss functions, at best it throws loss around 1800 on testing and 1850 on training data, Which in my opinion is quite acceptable, considering that if the bounding box is "dislocated" by 20px on every axis, its already 1600 ( before mean ).

However, when the network on the exact data i have trained it on, it result in extremely wrong results, almost like random no way it has around 1800 mean difference.

What would general approach be for dealing with things like this? Thanks for help.

Comment: Use more regularization.

Comment: i am using dropouts lazers and batchnorm layers in keras, however i tried the net on exactly same data i had fed it in training, and on them it got 1800 loss but the displayed result was random.

Comment: Have you normalized the cost? I mean you are using MSE or RSS? because the cost is significant, I don't think it's performing well enough.

Comment: i am using MSE, what do you mean normalizing cost? I am not well familiar with terminology, but maybe i am using it. I am not saying the loss is perfect, but if its just moved said 20px for now i am fine with it.

Comment: If you are using MSE, do you divide the mean square terms, if so, you are normalizing it.

Comment: No i am not, actually this is the first time i hear about it, would you mind to leaborate? Do you mean something like "loss of 1 img / mse" ?